# Regex for the following condition

Tags: php, javascript, regex, conditional-statements

I need a small help with regex for the following

1. Alphanumeric with only lower case alphabets allowed
2. Starts with number or alphabet
3. Allows period (.)
4. Doesn't allow consecutive periods No ..
5. Doesn't allow any other special characters

Thanks,
-GM

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Can the string end with a period?

Comment: "gimme dat regex" questions are not encouraged. Try first, post your regex and provide a few examples. If you don't make your own regex you'll never learn regex.

Answer (score 4):

```
^(?![^.]*\.\.)[a-z0-9][a-z0-9.]*$
```

The negative lookahead at the beginning covers your 4th requirement, everything else should be pretty straightforward.  `^` and `$` are beginning and end of string anchors, the character classes enforce the requirement that only lowercase letters, numbers, and `.` are allowed.

To add the length constraint (between 6 and 16 characters) just change the `*` to `{5,15}`.  `*` means "repeat the previous element zero or more times", `{n,m}` means "repeat the previous element between `n` and `m` times (inclusive)".  The reason `{5,15}` is used instead of `{6,16}` is that one character is already consumed by the first character class.  Here is the end result:

```
^(?![^.]*\.\.)[a-z0-9][a-z0-9.]{5,15}$
```

Comment: Since the question is also tagged javascript, I would like to mention that negative lookaheads are not supported in there.

Comment: Negative lookahead are supported in JS. Maybe not in every IE, but they are supported (iirc).

Comment: @basilikum - Actually, Javascript does support both positive and negative lookaheads. Just not **lookbehinds**. (I made the same mistake a while ago.)

Comment: @Py Really? I was totally convinced that it isn't supported. Ok, I take it back then. Must have confused it with something else.

Comment: How do I add constraint that the length is between 6-16 characters? Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some assistance without giving away the answer, as you'll learn the most.

1. To match from a certain combination of characters, *e.g.* alphanumeric, use **character classes**, *e.g.* `[a-z0-9]`. Note that this expression matches exactly *one* character. You must use **quantifiers** to match more than one, *e.g.* `+`.
2. To "start" or "end" with something, you must use **anchors**, `^` and `$`, before the first or after the last character, respectively. (Watch out, though. In a character class, the `^` **inverts** the character class.)
3. In regex, `.` has a special meaning as a **wildcard** (matching any character besides newline characters). Therefore you have to **escape** them, `\.`, to select the **literal** dot. Another way to escape the dot is to put it in a character class: `[.]`.
4. Non-consecutiveness is trickier. You will need to look up more information about **negative lookahead assertions** (or **lookaround assertions** in general).

All the bolded words are terms you can Google to learn.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say something along those lines: `/^[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z0-9]+)*\.?$/` (suppose that the line can end with a period)

Comment: Jason: I don't see how you'd match this. dot are followed by at least one letter or number :o

Answer (score 2):

Use this if the string may not end with a period:

```
/^[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z0-9]+)*$/
```

or this if it may:

```
/^[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z0-9]+)*\.?$/
```

Comment: basilikum, 2 dots in row passed due to missing anchors (strings like `foo..bar`)

Comment: Creative solution, not using lookaround assertions!

Answer (score 0):

This should be the best

```
^([a-z0-9]+\.?)+$
```